# React loading state on form submit with stripe.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, stripe-payments

I have a react checkout form using stripe.js (`<script id="stripe-js" src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>`). On submit, since stripe takes a few seconds to process the request and redirect the customer successfully, I'd like a loading animation on the checkout button based on loading state so the person who submits the form doesn't think there's an err or nothing's happening. however, on successful form submit, where `state = { ..., loading: true,}`, the loading state gets stopped by stripe's http request(s) (without stripe the loading circle keeps spinning):

[image]

The form works (the customer will eventually get redirected and the charge will process), but is there a way to maintain the loading state during stripe's requests?

```
import { CardElement, injectStripe, StripeProvider, Elements } from 'react-stripe-elements';
import { Button, Checkbox, Input, notification } from 'antd';

class _CardForm extends Component {
    state = {
        errorMessage: '',
        isSubscribe: true,
        // by default loading is false
        loading: false,
    };

    // call on form submit, set loading state: true
    enterLoading = () => {
        this.setState({ loading: true });
    };

    handleChange = ({ error }) => {
        if (error) {
            this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message });
        }
    };

    onChange = e => {
        console.log(`checked = ${e.target.checked}`);
        const isSubscribe = e.target.checked;
        this.setState({ isSubscribe });
    };

    handleSubmit = evt => {
        evt.preventDefault();
        if (this.props.stripe) {
            const { isSubscribe } = this.state;
            var onError = {};
            this.setState({ onError });
            this.props.stripe.createToken().then(token => this.props.handleResult(token, isSubscribe, this.props.amount));
        } else {
            console.log("Stripe.js hasn't loaded yet.");
        }
    };

    render() {
        var { isSubscribe, onError, subscribed } = this.state;
        if (!onError) onError = {};

        return (

            ...

            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
                        <label>
                            <CardElement
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                                thinking={this.props.thinking}
                                success={this.props.success}
                                {...createOptions()}
                            />
                        </label>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <Checkbox checked={isSubscribe} onChange={this.onChange}>
                                Subscribe
                            </Checkbox>

                            <Button
                                type="primary"
                                loading={this.state.loading} 
                                onClick={this.enterLoading}
                                htmlType="submit"
                            >
                               Submit <Icon type="cloud" />
                            </Button>{' '}
                        </div>
                    </form>
      )}
```

Comment: What do you do with onError? Can you include the full render method?

Comment: onError is a state used for result handling and displaying form validation errs. example: if (!validator.validate(email)) { var onError = {}; onError.email = 'Sorry, this input is not valid. Please try again.'; this.setState({ onError }); return;}

Comment: The reason why I am asking for the full render method, because you can have something like ```{onError.email.length ? <ErrorElemet /> : <form>...</form>```. You can check sample code with you logic here: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-visvesvaraya-18rgy. I added emulation of the stripe, and you code works fine